# Why is my 802.11n wireless bridge (WAY) slower than my 802.11g wireless bridge?

Tags: wireless-networking, 802.11n, 802.11g

I bought a [ZyXEL WAP3205 Wireless N Ethernet Bridge](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002LITI7K) to replace my [Buffalo Airstation WLI-TX4-G54HP Wireless G Ethernet Bridge](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BNDEZY).  I have a [Linksys WRT610N Wireless N Router](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001AZ01EO).  With the Buffalo bridge, I was getting around 3.0 MB /sec transfer rates.  With the ZyXEL, I get around 125 KB / sec.  The Wireless N device is not even in the ballpark of the Wireless G device I am trying to replace.

Any thoughts about what could be causing this, or steps I could take to troubleshoot the problem?

---

### Update

I was able to get the router to perform better, but it's still not quite cutting it.  I'm planning to return it and try a different brand.  Here's what I did:

1. I tried moving the bridge right next to the router.  This did indeed improve the throughput.  If the router was set to mixed mode (G+N connections allowed), I would get around the Max G speed (7 MB/sec).  When I set the network to N mode, I would get 14 MB/sec.  Better, but not the 30 MB/s I was hoping for.
2. For some reason, the new bridge takes time to "sync".  At first the throughput is horrible, but it eventually climbs to a respectable speed after 15-20 minutes or so.
3. I could live with 14 MB/sec, but the new bridge seems to "hang up" often.  Transfers move more quickly, but there is a large delay before the transfer starts.  This happens with web pages as well, for some reason.  I'm not sure what causes this behavior, but I'm going to punt on this particular bridge.

Comment: First thing to do would be to try the speeds on more computers, more routers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the channels used. I have a 802.11g router and just by changing channels, I can have the transfer rate vary by a factor of 15. Unfortunately, it depends on many factors, though. When testing, try to:

- Be as close to the router as you can,
- Stay away from having any obstacles between the router and the computer,
- Don't have both routers turned on at the same time - interference between the two (or any other router in your neighbourhood) can be a problem
- Check you are using the same parameters with the two - the encryption, WAN parameters, etc.
- Try to put the router in the open space (away from the walls, metal, etc.)
- If you have another computer or move your router to e.g. your friend's house and test it there, try testing with it - rarely you can see different computer-router combinations not work as expected

Also, note that you can change the "compatibility mode". If you have multiple devices connecting, the router has to adjust to the slowest one. Take a look at this:

- http://www.itworld.com/mobile-amp-wireless/100710/getting-most-80211n

a very good explanation of all the issues you can run into.